# Unable to figure out a SQL query involving 4 tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, wordpress

There is a query in SQL where I am badly stuck, I have tried every possible way I could but couldn't get the solution. I have 4 tables named: user, item, buys, rates.

```
CREATE TABLE User (
    id integer,
    name varchar(30),
    Primary Key (id)
)

INSERT INTO User(id, name)
VALUES
('1', 'Lorren'),
('2', 'Smith'),
('3', 'Stephen'),
('4', 'David'),
('5', 'Sophie'),
('6', 'Alex'),
('7', 'Henry'),
('8', 'Jasmine'),
('9', 'Anderson'),
('10', 'Bilal')

CREATE TABLE Item (
    id integer,
    description varchar(50),
    category varchar(30),
    price integer,
    Primary Key (id)
)

INSERT INTO Item(id, description, category, price)
VALUES
('50', 'Princess Diary', 'Book', '8'),
('51', 'Frozen', 'Book', '4'),
('52', 'Tangled', 'Book', '3'),
('53', 'Oak Table', 'Furniture', '370'),
('54', 'Doble Bed', 'Furniture', '450'),
('55', 'Metal Cupboard', 'Furniture', '700'),
('56', 'Levi 501', 'Clothes', '90'),
('57', 'Corduroy Coat', 'Clothes', '230'),
('58', 'Straight Trousers', 'Clothes', '45'),
('59', 'Black Sequin Top', 'Clothes', '85')


CREATE TABLE Buys (
    user integer,
    item integer,
    price integer,
    Primary Key (user, item),
    Foreign key (user) REFERENCES User(id),
    Foreign Key (item) REFERENCES Item(id)
)

INSERT INTO Buys
VALUES ('1', '52', '3'),
('1', '56', '90'),
('2','56','100'),
('2', '54', '450'),
('5', '53', '400'),
('5', '55', '700'),
('5', '59', '90'),
('6', '57', '230'),
('10', '58', '50'),
('8', '50', '8')


CREATE TABLE Rates (
    user integer,
    item integer,
    rating integer CHECK (0<=rating<=5),
    Primary Key (user, item),
    Foreign key (user) REFERENCES User(id),
    Foreign Key (item) REFERENCES Item(id)
)

INSERT INTO Rates
VALUES
('1', '52', '5'),
('1', '56', '3'),
('2', '54', '5'),
('2', '55', '4'),
('2', '56', '2'),
('5', '53', '5'),
('5', '55', '5'),
('8', '50', '1'),
('8', '55', '3'),
('9', '55', '4')
```

I have to find against each user all the items not bought by him, but display only those item/items among them which has/have the highest average rating. So the result should display only those item/items which were not bought by him and have the highest average rating. Rating is 1-5, and each item may have different ratings so avg rating can be calculated for each, but I am not able to find out items with highest avg rating gaainst each user which are not bought by him. I am working in MYSQL, I am stuck in here for 6 days and even my friends tried nobody could solve it. Can anybody help?

Expected Output considering the current tables should be like this:

```
User    Items With Highest Average      
Lorren     53
Lorren     54
Smith      52
Smith      53
Stephen    52
Stephen    53
Stephen    54
David      52
David      53
David      54
Sophie     52
Sophie     54
Alex       52
Alex       53
Alex       54
Henry      52
Henry      53
Henry      54
Jasmine    52
Jasmine    53
Jasmine    54
Anderson   52
Anderson   53
Anderson   54
Bilal      52
Bilal      53
Bilal      54
```

Comment: can you add the expected result.

Comment: Why don't you put in some of your attempts that you think got the closest. Without that it does feel a bit like a homework hand-off...

Comment: I guess you forgot the [Rating] column on your [Ratings] table

Comment: @jean Its kind of homework task, I've done rest of dozen queries, only this one remained unsolved, its not that simple as you wrote it, did you read we have to find items for each user, not bought by him and having highest average rating, so aggregate avg() will be used but how I can't figure it out

Comment: Are you aware of and familiar with subselects, or in MySQL terms, subqueries? They could probably help you get going here. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html

Comment: @jean 1) There could be items without any rating 2) No, a user can rate an item only once, but same item can be rated by multiple users

Comment: @RuneJacobsen Yes I know of them and tried them as well, still can't get the highest avg rating part in my result accurately.

Comment: @NoDisplayName Let me try display expected result

Comment: @PeterBowers Ok let me do it

Comment: @NoDisplayName I have updated the post to include expected output

Comment: This looks more like you're showing the user only 5-star average items that they have not bought (items 52, 53, and 54 are the only items with an average rating of 5, and they are the only ones in the result set).  Is that a fair assessment?

Comment: @PaulGriffin Its not like that. So far my tables have 10 rows so its a coincidence that for mort of the users, these unbought items have highest average rating, but there can be users, for whom an item with 3 average rating would be highest avg rating item among unbought items. There can be other rows added in tables later to add such users, whose unbought items may have 1,2 or 3 highest average rating.

Comment: So are you trying to get top 3 unbought items (in which case Lorren, Smith, and Sophie only show 2 items in your sample result)?  Top items over a certain rating?  Top item per category?  The result set unfortunately doesn't make this very clear.

Comment: I'm genuinely interested in this query, I want to make sure I'm totally clear on what expected results are.

Comment: @jean You have partially achieved the results, inaccuracies are there e.g. Levi 501 and Metal Cupboard shouldn't be in results with other items for Lorren, Smith and Sophie, as Levi and Metal Cupboard have average ratings less than other items for same users, we have to display only highest avg rating items

Comment: @PaulGriffin I appreciate your interest in it, actually my purpose is not to display only top 3 results for each user, it can be top 1, top or even top 6, depending upon how many items have the highest average rating, for example, lets suppose for Bilal, there are 8 items that are not bought by him and among those 8 only 2 items have the highest average rating and both have same values say 3.5 average rating, so both of them will be displayed

Comment: Ah!  I understand what you are looking for now.

Comment: @PaulGriffin in mysql somehow I feel use of aggregate function to find the average is limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, definitely not my prettiest work, especially since I don't usually work in MySQL (EDIT: SQLFiddle is back up. Fixed an inner group, now this works):

```
SELECT topItemsAllUsers.* FROM
  (SELECT 
    u.id AS userId, 
    u.name, 
    topItems.itemId
  FROM
    (SELECT 
      iwa.id AS itemId
    FROM
      (SELECT 
        MAX(AverageRating) AS MaxRating
      FROM
        (SELECT 
          i.id, 
          AVG(COALESCE(r.rating, 0)) AS AverageRating
        FROM Item i
        LEFT JOIN Rates r ON r.item = i.id
        GROUP BY i.id
        ) AS averages
      ) AS MaxOuterRating
      INNER JOIN 
      (SELECT 
        i.id, 
        AVG(COALESCE(r.rating, 0)) AS AverageRating
      FROM Item i
      LEFT JOIN Rates r ON r.item = i.id
      GROUP BY i.id
      ) as iwa ON iwa.AverageRating = MaxOuterRating.MaxRating
    ) as topItems
  CROSS JOIN
  User u
  ) as topItemsAllUsers
LEFT JOIN Buys b ON topItemsAllUsers.userId = b.user AND topItemsAllUsers.itemId = b.item
WHERE b.user IS NULL
```

[Here is the SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6ebed/48)

In TSQL, I would at least use a CTE for that table of average ratings.  This was a lot tougher than it looked initially!

EDIT: Some explanation follows.  The first thing to get is each item's average rating, using 0 for items with no rating (hence the `COALESCE()` statement):

```
(SELECT 
  i.id, 
  AVG(COALESCE(r.rating, 0)) AS AverageRating
FROM Item i
LEFT JOIN Rates r ON r.item = i.id
GROUP BY i.id)
```

This will list each item id once with its average rating.  I named this `averages`, and I actually used it query twice (naming it `iwa` the second time.   I don't remember what "iwa" was supposed to mean any more...), once to get the actual highest rating:

```
SELECT
  MAX(AverageRating) AS MaxRating
FROM averages
```

and named that `MaxOuterRating`, then `INNER JOIN`ed that result back onto `iwa`, on `AverageRating = MaxRating` , to only get item(s) with that highest rating:

```
SELECT
  iwa.itemId
FROM
MaxOuterRating
INNER JOIN iwa ON iwa.AverageRating = MaxOuterRating.MaxRating
```

This result is contained in the `topItems` alias.

Now that we have only the item(s) with the top rating, `CROSS JOIN` with `User` to get a table with every top item for every user:

```
SELECT 
  ... 
FROM
topItems
CROSS JOIN
Users
```

This result is in `topItemsAllUsers`.

Finally, do `LEFT JOIN` with `Buys` on both user id and item id, then restrict results to only those rows where there are no `Buys` records associated (This is usually called an exclude join):

```
SELECT 
  topItemsAllUsers.*
FROM
topItemsAllUsers
LEFT JOIN Buys b ON topItemsAllUsers.userId = b.user AND topItemsAllUsers.itemId = b.item
WHERE b.user IS NULL
```

Et viola.  None of the operations is particularly difficult, but they are nested up so badly, it was difficult to see how to attack.  I do not doubt this could be improved greatly, but this *does* return expected results.

Comment: I am thrilled almost to see your solution, you have done it Sir. I will appreciate if you will explain to me a little of what have you done in it

Comment: Bravo! You have explained it to make it easy for me. No doubt, it would have taken a lot of time of yours with brain, as nesting was complex. Thank you very much to spend your time for my query, brilliant job

Answer (score 1):

So just for starters, the list of items not bought by respective users is as follows, right?

```
    SELECT u.*
         , i.* 
      FROM user u 
      JOIN item i 
      LEFT 
      JOIN buys b 
        ON b.user = u.id 
       AND b.item = i.id 
     WHERE b.item IS NULL;
```

... in which case ...

```
SELECT x.* FROM
(
SELECT u.id user_id
     , u.name
     , i.id item_id
     , i.description
     , i.category
     , i.price
     , r.rating
  FROM user u 
  JOIN item i 
  LEFT 
  JOIN buys b 
    ON b.user = u.id AND b.item = i.id
  JOIN rates r
    ON r.item = i.id
 WHERE b.item IS NULL
) x
JOIN
(
SELECT u.id,r.rating 
  FROM user u 
  JOIN item i 
  LEFT 
  JOIN buys b 
    ON b.user = u.id AND b.item = i.id
  JOIN rates r
    ON r.item = i.id
  JOIN (SELECT AVG(rating) max_avg FROM rates GROUP BY item ORDER BY AVG(rating) DESC LIMIT 1) n
    ON n.max_avg = r.rating
 WHERE b.item IS NULL
 GROUP 
    BY u.id
 ) y
 ON y.id = x.user_id
AND y.rating = x.rating
ORDER 
  BY user_id,item_id;
```

... should produce the desired result

Edited to incorporate Paul Griffin's observation, although in doing so, I've perhaps made the query more convoluted than it needs to be.

Comment: This will get items with at least one rating == the top rating in the table, but does not limit to items whose average rating == top average rating.

Comment: @PaulGriffin You have done it, haven't you? I am looking at your solution, till now not able to grasp exactly what have you done in this solution. Result is accurate, I wonder if it will work on any number of rows in table with different rating items? I guess it should. You have done it Sir

Comment: @strawberry hey thanks for tweaking the solution and give a try to my question. You ppl are more helpful than I expected